# Boxplots ranked by mean value

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to show boxplots for multiple variables, and rank them by column means in descending order, just like in the *Performance Analytics* package. I use the following code to generate the boxplots:

```
zx <- replicate (5, rnorm(50))
zx_means <- (colMeans(zx, na.rm = TRUE))
boxplot(zx, horizontal = FALSE, outline = FALSE)
points(zx_means, pch = 22, col = "darkgrey", lwd = 7)
```

So far I have not been able to come up with a way to rank them as described above. I have tried using both *sort* and *order*, but without any satisfying results so far.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any ideas for how to use `points` with horizontal boxplots? When I change the boxplot to `horizontal = TRUE`, I'm not able to make the points line up with the boxplots.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a new question and not a comment to an existing question.

Comment: Sorry. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874512/adding-points-to-horizontal-boxplots).

Comment: Thanks, this makes individual QA threads much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` works fine for me!?:

```
colnames (zx) <- seq_len (ncol (zx))
boxplot(zx [, order (zx_means)], horizontal = FALSE, outline = FALSE)
points(zx_means [ order (zx_means)], pch = 22, col = "darkgrey", lwd = 7)
```

Comment: This produced the result I was looking for. I think I must have messed up the syntax when using `order`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this solved your problem, could you mark it as the correct answer using the tickmark below the vote counter?

Answer (score 3):

Using ggplot2 this gets the job done using your example data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

zx <- replicate (5, rnorm(50))

# ggplot2 uses long-shaped data.frame's, not matrices
zx_flat = melt(zx)[c(2,3)]
names(zx_flat) = c("cat","value")

# Here I calculate the mean per category
zx_flat = ddply(zx_flat, .(cat), mutate, mn = mean(value))
zx_flat = sort_df(zx_flat, "mn") # Order according to mean
# Here I manually set the order of the levels
# as this is the order ggplot2 uses
zx_flat$cat = factor(zx_flat$cat, levels = unique(zx_flat$mn))

# make the plot
ggplot(aes(factor(mn), value), data = zx_flat) + geom_boxplot()
```

and we get:

[image]

Comment: I have been looking into using ggplot2, but have not been able to figure out how to format the data. I will definately look into this. Thanks.