# Adding points to horizontal boxplots

Tags: r, alignment, boxplot

I use the following code to produce multiple boxplots, ranked by the mean value of the variables:

```
zx <- replicate (5, rnorm(50))
zx_means <- (colMeans(zx, na.rm = TRUE))
colnames (zx) <- seq_len (ncol (zx))
boxplot(zx [, order (zx_means)], horizontal = FALSE, outline = FALSE)
points(zx_means [ order (zx_means)], pch = 22, col = "darkgrey", lwd = 7)
```

([See this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871106/boxplots-ranked-by-mean-value))

When I change the code to `horizontal = TRUE`, I'm not able to make the points line up with the boxplots. Any ideas for how to properly add `points` to horizontal boxplots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give both x and y coordinates:

```
points(zx_means[order (zx_means)], seq_along(zx_means), 
       pch = 22, col = "darkgrey", lwd = 7)
```

or

```
points(zx_means, order (zx_means), pch = 22, col = "darkgrey", lwd = 7)
```