# Horizontal Boxplots in R: Is the plain old boxplot command not meant to plot mean points?

Tags: r, boxplot

This question was answered 2 years ago but it doesn't work in a strange way:

[Adding points to horizontal boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874512/adding-points-to-horizontal-boxplots?s=1|1.6797)

My data frame is eight columns of scores of test data. So, each column represents one student and their nine different test scores. I would like a box plot for each student all on the same plot.

When I use the given commands shown in the answer, I do get beautiful mean points on each of the eight horizontal box plots for my data frame but the *mean points are incorrectly on the wrong box plot*. This is very weird. There is no rhyme or reason for why this is--it's not like the means got shifted backwards and forwards or got shifted in some logical way.

When I use ggplot and geom_boxplot, the mean points are correctly plotted. So, I've been using ggplot and geom_boxplot. But I'm very curious (and in some ways, disturbed) that plotting the mean points over a box plot gives me the *correct* means but on the *incorrect* box.

Here is my data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(var1=c(100, 56, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 83, 100),
                 var2=c(100, 100, 100, 100, 50, 75, 100, 100, 100),
                 var3= c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 30, 100, 100),
                 var4= c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100),
                 var5= c(80, 60, 100, 100, 100, 50, 100, 100, 100),
                 var6= c(100, 50, 25, 17, 75, 14, 25, 100, 100),
                 var7= c(100,   100, 100, 33, 100, 100, 67, 100, 83),
                 var8= c(88, 79, 100, 40, 22, 100, 33, 75, 57))


# Here is me trying the answer that was given two years ago, 
# which works but plots out mean points like there is a poltergeist in R:

boxplot(mydata, horizontal=TRUE)

means<-colMeans(mydata) 

points(means,order(means),pch=18,col="red")
```

Any help/comments/suggestions would be much appreciated. Even if the comments are, "Who cares? Just use ggplot. It's better and it works!" I'm still learning R so ANYTHING is useful to me. Right now I feel like I should use ggplot for everything, regardless of how quickly and how many times I need to visualize my data.

Comment: Your y values don't correspond to the correct mean and `order(mean)` is not the correct order `points(means,1:8,pch=18,col="red")`. the order was changed in that question because the box order was changed

Comment: Boxplots are intended to show order statistics (you might need to look that term up, too), not means and standard deviations. Read up on non-parametric statistics.